# Android geolocation not responding right after turning location on

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation

I have the following simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn').click(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        $.post('serverhandler.php', { 'lat' : position.coords.latitude, 'lng' : position.coords.longitude }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
    ,handle_errors
    );              
});
```

});

With this I get the location of the user, and it works ok if the location is already on in the mobile settings.
The thing is that if the user enters the site with the location off and turn it on when asked, the android mobile doesn't send anything. It can be fixed by opening google maps and retrieving its location, and then going back to the website, but I'd like a way to do so within the site.
The same code works fine on the same conditions with IOS, and windows phone retrieves the wrong location, with the same fix of android(but with here maps instead of google maps). Any ideas on why it works like that and some way to work around it? Thanks!

Comment: Location takes time.  It won't always be immediately available, especially if using GPS from a cold start.  Don't assume it will return instantly.

Comment: The thing is that when I open google maps it can get the correct position, and only after that my website can. Why my code can't do what the map do? Isn't there avaiable coding for it?

Comment: Opening Google maps turns on GPS.  SO its starting up the GPS subsystem for you.  With the GPS susbsystem already on, you can just get the position instantly because the system will give you the values it just gave maps.

Comment: So you are saying that the only way to start android's GPS is to open google maps?

Comment: No.  I'm saying that if you don't already have it open, it takes a few seconds to a minute or two to turn on.

Comment: Hm, okay. My question was because from what I tested opening google maps made it turn on almost instantly (or really faster) than just trying to retrieve the location from my website. Anyway, thank you very much for making it clear!